# SSRS Indentation of expand icon

Tags: reporting-services, expand, ssrs-2016

Using: Visual Studio 2015 with SQL Server data tools 14

I have a report that displays logs, and groups by associated iterative parent.  Each row can be expanded if there are child rows.  I have padded the cells by iterative depth to give a tree like appearance.  The issue I have is that when the expand icon is present it pushes the text horizontally to allow space. See image.

[image]

In this instance item 24 is a child to item 23, however the text has been pushed across further to the right so the tree layout is disrupted.  Items 27 & 31 are at the same level - both being children of 22, but appear to be different.

I have used the technique of a dummy column which can be displayed or hidden to the far right for showing additional details. This approach does not work mid line, as hiding the cell removes the background image, and potentially leaves a lot of spaces.

Is there any way I can test if the icon is displayed or not and adjust my padding in code to suit?

Many thanks.

Edit:
It is possible to test the database to see if children exist, and use that to see if the icon should be displaying.  This however requires loading the data set, and cross referencing back to itself to check for children.  This makes the query far more expensive, but it does work.  See image below:
[image]

Code used for padding:

```
=cstr(2 + ((LEVEL()) * 10) + ((1-Fields!HasChild.Value) * 15) ) + "pt"
```

HasChild returns a 0 or 1 depending on internal logic. Would prefer not to generate this in SQL as SSRS must "know" that it has displayed the icon.

Many thanks.

Comment: Knowing your data structures would help here.  Are you able to count the number of child groups?  If so, use that in the cell padding to conditionally indent the `Procedure` string

Comment: @iamdave That was actually what I've just done.  I'll post a full answer shortly.  I performed a db side calculation to test for child elements and used that in my calculation.  Not the most efficient as it requires cross referencing the result set back to itself, but it worked.  Would prefer not to have the database load though, any other options gratefully received. +1 for that though.